# Ошибка при использовании команд artisan

Tags: laravel, php

Установил laravel проект при помощи composer, сам php установлен корректно, однако
стоит попытаться использовать в терминале любую комманду, например, php artisan list, как получаю следующее:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter' not found in E:\Users\mello_000\PhpstormProjects\larablog\bootstrap\compiled.php on line 8558
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Monolog\\Formatter\\LineFormatter' not found","file":"E:\\Users\\mello_000\
\PhpstormProjects\\larablog\\bootstrap\\compiled.php","line":8558}}
E:\Users\mello_000\PhpstormProjects\larablog>
```

Не могу понять, в чем дело.

Comment: php artisan dump-autoload
тоже не вылетает?

Answer (score 1):

composer update делали?

Answer (score 0):

Если не поможет:

```
composer update
```

посмотрите не добавлены ли у Вас лишние провайдеры в файле ***app/config/app.php***. Так же взгляните ***app/start/artisan.php***, может там у Вас прописаны несуществующие кастомные команды.